# Python - Binary search being too slow and crashes computer - how can I improve the algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I have been working on a binary search problem.

Instead of matching one key number to a given list, the problem required me to match a list (list B) of keys to another list (list A). If a key matches a number in list A, then the output should return the first index in A where the number is present. If the key number is not present in list A, then return -1

Say that list A and list B are:

```
A = [1, 5, 8, 12, 13]
B = [8, 1, 23, 1, 11]
```

Since 8 is present in both list, the output is 2 because 8 in list A is at [2]. Using this logic, the overall final output should become:

```
matched_list = [2, 0, -1, 0, -1]
```

Below is my code. It would be much appreciated if you could also find any logic errors within in lines, however, my biggest concern is the run time. When I press enter on my computer, it took ages to process, and the software (I used VS Code) eventually crashes.

I had 16GB RAM and Intel Core i7, so it shouldn't be the device that dragged it down, but the algorithm.

```
def binary_search(A, B, n):
# We match the numbers in key list, B, to the numbers in A

    low, high = 0, n-1
    # low limit is initialised to A[0], the first number of list A
    # high limit initialised to the last number of the list, A[n-1]

    matched_list = []

    for i in B:
        middle = (high+low)//2

        while low <= high:
            if i > A[middle]:
                low = middle+1 

            elif i < A[middle]:
                high = middle-1 
            
            else:
                matched_list.append(middle)
    
        if low > high:
            return(-1)

    return(matched_list)

A = [1, 5, 8, 12, 13]
B = [8, 1, 23, 1, 11]
n = 5  # this is the length of list A


print(binary_search(A, B, n))
```

Would there be a way to improve my algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed bugs in the function. see this code:

```
def binary_search(A, B, n):
    matched_list = []

    for i in B:
        low, high = 0, n - 1
        while low <= high:
            middle = (high + low) // 2
            if i > A[middle]:
                low = middle + 1
            elif i < A[middle]:
                high = middle - 1
            else:
                matched_list.append(middle)
                break

        if low > high:
            matched_list.append(-1)

    return matched_list
```

Comment: Ah thanks, so the reason the programme didn't stop was that I forgot to break the loop. It makes sense now. And thank you for fixing the other bug as well

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
while low <= high:
            if i > A[middle]:
                low = middle+1 

            elif i < A[middle]:
                high = middle-1 
            
            else:
                matched_list.append(middle)
```

The `else` statement doesn't break, because of which it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Adding a `break` statement would solve it.
Suggestion: Since maps/dictionaries tend to be faster, you can use them to effectively solve this in `O(N)` rather than `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: I see my problem now, thank you for reminding me of that loop. So the reason that my programme never stopped and output an answer was that I didn't break it....... And yep I will have a look at the map for improvement

Answer (score 1):

**1st - you can't use binary search if space isn't sorted.**

**2nd - if you want better algorithm use maps and complexity will be linear**

**3rd - if you want to use a binary search, you can easily insert your values in set and then find the answer with lower_bound.**

Answer (score 1):

@cliff_leaf, in your case, it would be easier just to use dict() to save the number-index in dictionary for a quick O(1) lookup later by B:
(Binary Search is prob. not appropriate in the case.) You could adjust the code to break/exit when you find the first matching number - 8 and stop, if that's what you want - find the first matching.

```py
>>> A = [1, 5, 8, 12, 13]
>>> B = [8, 1, 23, 1, 11]
>>> aa = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(A)}
>>> aa
{1: 0, 5: 1, 8: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4}
>>> for n in B:
    if n in aa: print(aa[n])

    
2
0
0
```

Comment: Wow to be honest I have never thought of an algorithm like this. Dictionary and enumerate function, I will have a look at and implement these to my programme. Thanks

Comment: Glad it can help. Wanna upvote my post then?

Comment: Think I already did though, maybe the system was being slow